# How to check if query returned true or false in replacement for mysql_error() in PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am creating a web based application, and I am using PDO for my database. I have a query that selects everything from login table where `username=something` and `password=something`.

My code:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$query->bindParam(':username',$username);
$query->bindParam(':password',$password); 
$query->execute();
```

However I want to check if the query returned true or false. For example in mysql we used to say:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'  "); 
if($query == false){
    die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

My question is, how do I check if the query returned false or true using PDO and gives an error? This will help me get errors on my code during development.

What am I going to replace the `mysql_error()` with?

Comment: looks like your second query is syntactially incorrect

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more descriptive. I also removed unconstructive comments from the body, and indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: Prasad Khode anything to help?

Comment: Thanks i appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We set PDO in exception mode.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

We wrap queries with try/catch block. If an Exception is thrown, we  catch it. That's the equivalent of using `if(!mysql_query($query)) echo mysql_error();`

Your example would be

```
try
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
    $query->bindParam(':username',$username);
    $query->bindParam(':password',$password); 
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Whoopsie, an error occurred! Message: ". $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. it has worked for me. I appreciate this